# LAN NAS lost connection

Tags: windows-7, nas, lan

Without warning, I lost connection to my NAS from my Win 7 HP laptop.  The LAN printer works fine, but I cannot get the network search to find the NAS.  I have three other computers, their connections remain unaffected. I've tried everything short of reinstalling the Win 7 OS.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Can you ping it?
Can you \Nas'sName into a share?

Comment: or at least \\NAS's IP  to get to it?